# Python: How to replace letters in string using lists?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

Basically, I'm creating a really low tier cipher. I've set up a bit of code to randomize each character, but I can't figure out how to replace a string with these. This is the code I attempted

```
characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ",", " ", "!", "?"]

characters2 = ['h', 'i', '.', 'u', 'o', 'x', 'q', 'b', 'y', 'z', 's', 'd', 'm', 'w', 'k', 'n', 'j', '?', 'a', 'v', 't', 'r', 'e', 'f', 'c', ' ', '!', 'l', 'g', 'p', ',']

string = string.replace(characters[],characters2[])
```

In this example I was basically expecting being able to input a string, such as "string" and get back the encrypted string, which in this case would come back as "av?ywq". The only other way I could think of working this out would basically be to write

```
string = string.replace(characters[0],characters2[0]).replace(characters[1],characters2[1]).replace...
```

for the entire length of the list, which I could do, but it would be extremely tedious and take up way too much space.

Doing a loop would of course mean that if, for example, the "i" in "string" were replaced with an "s", and then the "s" in string were replaced with an "h", it would come out "htrhng", replacing both the "i" and "s" with the "h".

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. For these type of problems, it's probably smarter to build a new string and enter in the appropriate character based on its value in the original string. I would also *highly* consider using a dictionary that maps `old_character` --> `new_character`

```py
character_mapping = {"a": "h", "b": "i" , ...}  

old_string = "my old string"

new_string = ""

for char in old_string:
    new_string += character_mapping[char]
```

This way, you don't need to worry about indexes (from the lists). Also, please don't use `string` as a variable name as it's the name of a default package included in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary to map one list item to another .

```
string = "string"

characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ",", " ", "!", "?"]
characters2 = ['h', 'i', '.', 'u', 'o', 'x', 'q', 'b', 'y', 'z', 's', 'd', 'm', 'w', 'k', 'n', 'j', '?', 'a', 'v', 't', 'r', 'e', 'f', 'c', ' ', '!', 'l', 'g', 'p', ',']
    
dic =  {} 
for l1,l2 in zip(characters,characters2):
    dic[l1]=l2
    
result = ""
for letter in string:
    result = result + dic[letter]
print(result)

#Output = av?ywq
```

Answer (score 0):

[`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is an option.

```
import string

characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ",", " ", "!", "?"]
characters2 = ['h', 'i', '.', 'u', 'o', 'x', 'q', 'b', 'y', 'z', 's', 'd', 'm', 'w', 'k', 'n', 'j', '?', 'a', 'v', 't', 'r', 'e', 'f', 'c', ' ', '!', 'l', 'g', 'p', ',']

text = "string"
table = text.maketrans(dict(zip(characters, characters2)))
print(text.translate(table))
```

Output:

```
av?ywq
```